# Navigation Links do not work outside of the App Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-router

I have 4 files: App.js, navbar.js, signIn.js, signUp.js. I expect the navbar to be displayed at the top of each page that the user navigates. The links in the navbar work on the homepage but the links are disabled on any other page.

I've tried installing react-bootstrap through npm instead of using the cdn but that did not change the issue. I tried creating another group of components called "NavigationLinks.js" but that didn't work either. I'm at a loss as to what else I could do.

Here are the relevant files:

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/layout/navbar'
import Dashboard from './components/feed/dashboard'
import SignIn from './components/auth/signIn'
import SignUp from './components/auth/signUp'
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
      <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="App">
              <Navbar/>
              <Switch>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard}/>
                  <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn}/>
                  <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp}/>
              </Switch>
          </div>
      </BrowserRouter>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Navbar.js

```
import { Switch, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Navbar, Nav, Form, FormControl, Button, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
//import './navbar.css';

class navbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <div>
                  <Navbar>
                      <Navbar.Brand as={Link} to='/'>Rekindle</Navbar.Brand>
                      <Navbar.Collapse>
                          <Nav className="mr-auto">
                              <NavItem eventkey={1} href="/">
                                  <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/" >Home</Nav.Link>
                              </NavItem>
                              <NavItem eventkey={1} href="/signup">
                                  <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/signup" >Sign Up</Nav.Link>
                              </NavItem>
                              <NavItem eventkey={1} href="/signin">
                                  <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/signin" >Login</Nav.Link>
                              </NavItem>
                          </Nav>
                      </Navbar.Collapse>
                  </Navbar>
              </div>

              {/*this div works for the routing  */}
              <div>

              </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default navbar;
```

The code compiles without errors, but I want to be able to navigate back to the homepage from the signIn and signUp routes.

Answer (score 1):

In your code snippet I found some issue, like you missed to `import` `react` only.

Any file you create, you need to import react like,

```
import React from 'react'; //default
```

Also you are extending `Component` in your `navbar component` which is also need to import from `react` package.

**2 ways to extend `Component`.**

**Way 1,**

```
import React from 'react';

class navbar extends React.Component{
   render(){
     return(
       <div>...</div>
     )
   }
}

export default navbar;
```

**Way 2,**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

class navbar extends Component{
   render(){
     return(
       <div>...</div>
     )
   }
}

export default navbar;
```

You missed this in you `navbar` component.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-dfh3u?fontsize=14) is the working code snippet for you.

Comment: Oh, I guess I must've clipped the import react statements when copying the code. I still have the same issue.

Comment: @IkechukwuAnude have you checked the demo?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like these integration errors are common and you are suppose to use: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-router-bootstrap

Comment: This didn't seem to affect my problem. I am still confused as to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Ok, I haven't use the stack that you are using but checking the docs: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navs/#nav-link-props, I see that `Nav.Link` doesn't have a property `to` that is the one used by react-router `Link`. Are you sure the `to` property is correctly passed from `Nav.Link` to `Link`? I am just guessing but I think the integration library will deal with this kind of things.